# Local Area Network Configuration Question

Tags: networking, router, vpn, dhcp

Comcast installed a Juniper Universal Access Router ACX1100, I plugged our switch to the port that the technician told us that is in/out port. But nothing happened, after reading and asking I was told that I need a managed switch to be configured with the gateway IP and that IP is a /29. That's where I got lost. According to him there are 6 usable IP's.

example:

Gateway: 192.168.120.161/29
Usable Range: 192.168.120.162 - 192.168.120.167

One of my multiple questions is what hardware do I need to be able to connect my PC's?, I configured a managed switch, but when I connect my laptop to it I get Unidentified Network and No Internet Connection.

I have been reading and I think I need a VPN with DHCP server integrated.

If some one can help me I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in order to accurate assess your situation, we need to know exactly what kind of configuration you set on the managed switch you purchased, also which managed switch did you purchase?

Also currently on your laptop's NIC, what IP is assigned on there?

Either on your old unmanaged switch or on the managed switch, you can try assigning one of the addresses from the /29 block that the technician told you about statically. And the default-gateway with the addresses you posted in your question.

Comment: The managed Switch is a HP Procurve 3500yl-48G-PWR  and a ProSafe 8-Port Gigabit VPN Firewall FVS318G. So I was able to configure internet connection and set DHCP server on the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

/29 is the subnet mask, it can also be expressed as 255.255.255.248. Basically it defines which part of the IP is the network ID and which part of IP is the host ID.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.